# How to render multiple times on the same response object with ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a situation where I need multiple renders to occur with the same response object in an ExpressJS application. (Basically one HTTP request triggers multiple back-end requests, all of which can begin rendering results to the page immediately as they complete.) The problem is that I need each one to render a view (i.e. I don't think I can use `res.write()`), and as far as I can tell, there is no way for `res.render()` to not end the response or write headers each time it is called.

What am I missing?

Comment: How can you respond twice to a single HTTP request?

Comment: It's not responding twice - it's just that I want to be able to stream the output to the page from multiple functions. The HTTP request results in several API calls to other services that generate portions of the response. Rather than waiting for all of them to respond and rendering the page all at once, I want there response object to remain "open" so that I can write views (more accurately a view partials) out to it until all the API calls complete.

Comment: Ah, `res.write` is going to be your only option then. Of course, there is also the option of loading part of the page via `res.render`, then using AJAX to load the rest.

Comment: I was afraid of that - I'd prefer to not have the client-side need to "know" about the back-end logic. There's no magic way to get res.write to generate its output from a view is there?

Comment: What about `res.partial`? Could you break up your rendering into multiple partials, then send the final result with `res.render`?

Comment: I tried that, but it appears from my testing that `res.partial` also sends headers, so the second time it is called it throws an exception.

Comment: `res.render` also seems to take a 3rd param called `fn` that apparently prevents an immediate response. Perhaps you can hook into that to do some other processing on the response body? You may not have access to view rendering, unless you find some "private" methods within the response method that you can monkey with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Express compiles the template using an engine like EJS, Jade etc.

The data is then rendered using response.send: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L76-131

As you can see there, at the end there is `this.end...`, which means response.end(...).

If you want do achieve sending multiple views, you must compile those views yourself using the view engine and then create a function similar to response.send (which I gave you the link above), but be careful not to send the headers twice or call response.end before the last view is rendered.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it is the most technically appropriate solution. In my case, I redesigned the way I was making multiple calls to aggregate the responses and only render once because it seemed like a better approach. alessioalex's guidance is spot on though for anyone who wants to approach this - the pointer to the code is exactly where you need to start.